# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 31 Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to convert a varchar column to bigint and keep getting an error.

I've tried to alter the column using every exact or approximate data types and it will not convert. I've trimmed and cleaned the data and it still has issues.

**This is the code that I have been using.**

```
USE [database1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1]
ALTER COLUMN [column1] bigint

GO
```

**These are the results of the code above**

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 31
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If there are non numeric value in your `column1` column, then the statement will fail.  It's a common sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would appear to have invalid values.  So, update them away:

```
update t
    column1 = convert(varchar(255), try_convert(bigint, column1));
```

Then try changing the column type.

Or, just add a computed column:

```
alter table t add column1_bi as (try_convert(bigint, column1));
```

You can see what the bad values are using:

```
select column1
from t
where try_convert(bigint, column1) is null and column1 is not null;
```

Comment: I tried your first solution and it worked great. Thank you for the multiple solutions, it allowed me to experiment and learn some more code. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.